# Image color getting changed in Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am having a strange issue with navigation drawer. I created navigation drawer using default template provided with Android Studio and it created it using menu.xml file. Now problem is that whenever I add image to navigation drawer list item it's color is changed to grey despite any color image.  here is one image from navigation drawer

[image: icon]

As you can see the color of image is green but when added to navigation drawer it looks like [image: Navigation Drawer]

I don't know what's causing this

Here is menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_camera"
            android:icon="@drawable/clock"
            android:title="Home" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/mega_event"
            android:title="Mega Events" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
            android:icon="@drawable/tickets"
            android:title="My Tickets" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
            android:icon="@drawable/profile"
            android:title="Profile" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings"
            android:title="Settings" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
            android:icon="@drawable/logout"
            android:title="Logout" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Here the drawable in the first item is the one I posted

And activity theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style>
```

and navigation drawer activity class

```
    public class ActivityNavigationDrawer extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new FragmentTabs()).commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yourNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);  try adding it in your oncreate..revert back

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use directly `app:itemIconTint` for icon color change and `app:itemTextColor` for text item color change in navigation view.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content Layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_awesome_toolbar" />

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemIconTint="#FF0000"
        app:itemTextColor="#D2691E"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create following xml selector files like `navigation_item_icon.xml` into your `res/color/` directory for Navigation Menu Icon tint

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- NORMAL -->
    <item android:color="@color/navigation_item_iconColor" android:state_checked="false" />
    <!-- CHECKED -->
    <item android:color="@color/navigation_item_iconColor_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

---

Create `navigation_item_text.xml` into your `res/color/` directory for navigation menu item text color tint.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- NORMAL -->
    <item android:color="@color/navigation_item_textColor" android:state_checked="false" />
    <!-- CHECKED -->
    <item android:color="@color/navigation_item_textColor_selected" android:state_checked="true" />
</selector>
```

---

Then you have to use `navigation_item_icon.xml` and `navigation_item_text.xml` into your navigation view as tint.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Content Layout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_below="@id/my_awesome_toolbar" />

    <!-- Navigation Drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/navigation_item_icon"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/navigation_item_text"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Using just this line from your code helped me `app:itemIconTint="#ffffff"`

Comment: Update your answer with only this line as rest is misleading

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setItemTextColor` and `setItemIconTintList` for set text color tint and icon color tint to item of NavigationDrawer, this methods set color to any state of NavigationDrawer item.
To use this methods first add this code to end of onCreateView:

```
    int[][] states = new int[][]{
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked},// unchecked state
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}, // checked state
    };

    int[] colors = new int[]{
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary),
            ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
    };

    ColorStateList colorStateList = new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    navigationView.setItemTextColor(colorStateList);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(colorStateList);
```

This code set color to unchecked state and checked state. You can set color to other states.

Color array and state array should be have equals member count. You can select color whatever you want. You can use Color class or like the sample use resource.
In this link you can find list of available states [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html).

Comment: what would be values for states and colors?? and text color is perectly fine I am only having problem with images

Comment: I edit my answer. Used state in my sample resolve your problem, You can remove setItemTextColor but I suggest you use it because if don't use it maybe set different color to text and icons.

Comment: but I am not making any kind of selector for navigation drawer. It's just simple and images are getting change when I add them to navigation drawer

Comment: You don't need to any selector. You can use Color class.For example you can use Color.Red instead of ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary).

Comment: but I think this would not change color of image

Answer (score 2):

Use this -

```
      navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to use selectors. The code in the following SO question with a minor modification is all you need to get the color changes done: [Navigation View's selectors behave incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161403/navigation-views-selectors-behave-incorrectly/34566602)

just replace `android:state_selected` with `android:state_checked`

Comment: I am not creating any selector

Answer (score 0):

you try activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_menu_item_color"
        android:background="#414144"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and you setDrawer in activity_main_drawer

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="">

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_camara"
            android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_home_active_icn"
            android:title="HOME"

            app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_my_switch"
            />
        </item>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_gallery" android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_news_inactive_icn"
            android:title="NEWS"

            app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_my_switch2"
            />

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow" android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_ssotv_inactive_icn"
            android:title="SSO TV" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage" android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_about_inactive_icn"
            android:title="COMICS" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_manage_1" android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_member_inactive_icn"
            android:title="MEMBER" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_card" android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_card_inactive_icn"
        android:title="CARD" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_map" android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_map_inactive_icn"
            android:title="MAP" />
        <item android:id="@+id/nav_setting" android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_about_inactive_icn"
            android:title="SETTING" />
    </group>

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_share" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item android:id="@+id/nav_send" android:icon="@drawable/sidemenu_close_btn"
                android:title="SIGN OUT" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Comment: I can't try this now as I don't have that code with me anymore.